# Legendre-Fenchel transform

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, convex-analysis

Suppose $F:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ is a convex continuous function.

Moreover, for any $x\in \mathbb R^n$,
$$
\limsup_{\lambda\to\infty} \frac {|F(\lambda x)|}{\lambda}<\infty.
$$
I would like to conclude that the Legendre-Fenchel transform
$$
F^*(y) =\sup_{x\in\mathbb R^n} (\langle y,x\rangle-F(x))
$$
is continuous on its domain (which is a closed set).

Comment: I might be mistaken here, but $F^*$ should be a convex function and convex functions are themselves continuous (on their domain).

Comment: @mlk: convex functions don’t have to be continuous on the boundary of their domain.

Comment: This does not seem to be true. If $F\equiv 0$, then the conjugate is the indicator of $\{0\}$ which is not continuous in $0$.

Comment: Maybe there is some confusion regarding "continuous on its domain". If the domain is not the full space, the conjugate will never be continuous on the domain, because it has to jump to $+\infty$ on the boundary. So are you asking if the conjugate has full domain?

Comment: How do you define the domain: the set of $y$ for which it is finite?

Comment: And here $F^*$ has never full domain, for the condition implies that $\text{dom}F^*$ does not contain lines (which btw in finite dimension even implies it is bounded, and that $F$ is Lipschitz, I think)

Comment: Thank you very much. It was most helpful. What I actually need is contained in the answer to this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/341403/when-do-convexity-and-lower-semicontinuity-imply-continuity